# ServerAlias with SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, serveralias

I would like to know if the SSL certification would still be valid in the scenario. By valid I mean it will display both sites with SSL certificate without any issues or errors etc.

I have two external URL's `hello.com` and `world.com` for example. and I have an internal url at `internal.com` for instance. both `hello.com` and `world.com` resolve to one IP address lets say `8.8.8.8`. Below is my setup for apache virtual host using IP-based SSL.

```
<VirtualHost 8.8.8.8:443>
    ServerName hello.com
    ServerAlias world.com www.world.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/hello.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/hello.key
    Redirect / https://hello.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Location />     
        ProxyPass http://internal.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://internal.com:8080/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

So I guess the question is above so, go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SSL certificates are valid on a single domain only.  Please see my overview of SSL certificate types here:

https://serverfault.com/a/509303/35258

Either you want to use a multi-domain SSL certificate or consider creating two-virtual host containers and using a SSL certificate on each that matches their respective domains.